pyvisa equivalent for serial.serial.rts=False
I have a specific instrument that needs to deassert the RTS line before communication can work. On an old script I was doing a basic serial.serial.rts=False. What is the equivalent with pyvisa?
I tried with pyvisa.constants.LineState but could not manage to replicate the behavior.
Old code that works:
instrument = serial.Serial('COM6', 
                           baudrate=4800, 
                           parity='N', 
                           bytesize=8, 
                           stopbits=1, 
                           xonxoff=False,
                           rtscts=False, 
                           dsrdtr=True)
instrument.rts = False

Now with pyvisa I have:
rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()
instrument = rm.open_ressource('ASRL6::INSTR')
instrument.baud_rate=4800
instrument.data_bits=8
instrument.flow_control=VI_ASRL_FLOW_DTR_DSR
instrument.parity=Parity.none
instrument.stop_bits=StopBits.one

And it is not working, which I assume comes from not deasserting the RTS line...

instrument.set_visa_attribute(VI_ATTR_ASRL_RTS_STATE, LineState.unasserted) looks like it does the job.  There are probably some imports and module names that I haven't specified, I'm not in a position to actually test this code.

Tried it and unfortunately it does not:
pyvisa.errors.VisaIOError: VI_ERROR_NSUP_ATTR (-1073807331): The specified attribute is not defined or supported by the referenced object.
